# Use Perfetto to Debug Jank

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, perfetto

I've been reading through the Perfetto website and I am able to take a stack trace, but I don't understand how to actually "track down" the cause of jank in my application.  The tool is somewhat overwhelming.  I believe I find the point where the jank occurs but there doesn't seem to be an obvious link to another process or thread.

How can I make the correlation between the cause and effect? Are there parts of the tool that help with this?